# laravel 3 way pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relational-database

I've one many to many relationship between Entities and Affiliated Tables,
basically an affiliated can attend to many entities(example, medical services, dentist offices). One Entity can be visited by one or many affiliated. 
 Additionaly , one or more benefits can be occupied by one affiliated in a particular entity. As shown in the  image.
    [image]

I want to be able to answer queries like, which benefits where used by the affiliated in a particular entity.

Should i create a new Model, how should i rewrite the many-to-many relationship for ORM.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMO, Affiliated and Entities (many to many), Affiliated and Benefits (one to many) should be fine. 
No need to add Benefits to Affiliated_has_Entities.

Comment: @Arata_Artorias , One affiliated can have many Benefits, and One Benefit can be taken by many Affiliates

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a `Affiliated_has_Entities` model.
You could write the relationships as below, remember to check for arguments and its order in the `belognsToMany` relationship (sorry for misspelled words)

**Entities model**

```
public function afilliateds(){
return $this->belongsToMany('Afilliated', 'Afilliated_has_Entities');
}
```

**Afilliated model**

```
public function entities(){
return $this->belongsToMany('Entities', 'Afilliated_has_Entities');
}

public function benefits(){
return $this->belongsToMany('Entities', 'Afilliated_has_Entities');
}
```

**Benefits model**

```
public function entites(){
return $this->belongsToMany('Entities', 'Afilliated_has_Entities');
}
```

And so on..

I hope it helps

Comment: Ok, i'd give this a try .